# Cannot read property 'email' of null with Firebase cloud storage and authentication. saving a picture as the username

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I have created a store in firbase storage of images from users logged in that are saved with as their email in a "profile-images" folder.

When I try to extract the images, firebase says the email it cannot read property email of null.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'


export class AccountPage extends Component {


//the upload of image to firebase cloud storage (works fine)
  Upload = (e) => {   
    let file = e.target.files[0];   
    let storageRef = firebase
    .storage()
    .ref("profile-images/" +firebase.auth().currentUser.email);

    let task = storageRef.put(file);
  }

//storage of the url, no problem stated.
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             download: null,
        }

      }


//always says "cannot read property email of null" even with the if statement

componentDidMount(){
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser.email != null)
    {

//to define storageRef        
    let storageRef =  firebase
    .storage()
    .ref("profile-images/" +firebase.auth().currentUser.email);

    //location of the highlighted problem,
    storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    this.setState({
       download:url
    });     
    console.log(url)       
    })
  }
  //end of problem's location

}

//the upload file input and the image to be displayed location
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
         <img src={this.state.download} height="42" width="42"/>

    <input type="file" onChange={this.Upload}/>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AccountPage
```

Any suggestions of how to proceed are welcome and thank you for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: The error message is suggesting that `firebase.auth().currentUser` is null, which means no user is currently signed in.

Comment: i have run consolelogs and tests to show that a user is signed in. But also the process works without suggesting email is null if i put what is in the "componentDidMount" in the function "upload" but then the image only shows after it has just been uploaded.

Comment: If you look I have stated the upload works, and thus the user has to have been signed in. As the same "email" it is saying is null is also the email that identifies the image uploaded.

Comment: The error is that `firebase.auth().currentUser` is `null` and thus cannot access an `email` property from it, not that `firebase.auth().currentUser.email` is `null`.

Comment: I will point out that the current user isn't known immediately on page load. You should use an auth state observer to get a callback when it's first known.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data

Comment: thanks so much dug, your answer solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This means that `firebase.auth().currentUser` is null when the component first mounts.

You can try something like

```
componentDidMount(){
  if (firebase.auth().currentUser && firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
  // do the other stuff
```

but if it's not firing then you'll probably need to catch it with `componentDidUpdate`

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = {
     download: null,
     loginCheck: false,
   }
 }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  if (!prevProps.loginCheck && firebase.auth().currentUser) {
    setState({ loginCheck: true });
    // do the other stuff
```

Alternatively, you pass `firebase.auth().currentUser` as a prop from a parent component and use that instead.